# What is the GIT workflow for when 2 developers share a centralized repository between them

Tags: git

Me and another guy have recently been working on an app that is shared using git.
As its a small team we have not bothered  with branches so we thought we can just check into the main HEAD.
Our problem seems to be when we both check in and push. Basically one of us gets fast-forward errors and cannot check in. Sometimes we can force the change in but this seems to strip out the other persons commits - not nice. The other person usually can commit OK but it seems to be preventing the other person to work concurrently.

We thought it was as easy as

Do a fetch to get latest
commit and push out changes

but as mentioned this causes the above problems for us. This is a very simple workflow so we thought the commands to do it would be straight forward.

I guess is there anyone who got a workflow like this working using GIT ?
What are the correct commands to use ?

Frank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is `rebase` your local master branch before pushing your changes.  This will allow you to pull in master from origin, and then apply your work "on top" of it.

So, your commands would be:

```
git pull origin master

<code code code>

git add .

git commit -m "some message about <code code code>"

git pull --rebase origin master

git push origin master
```

Git Ready has some [really good documentation](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html) on pulling with the `--rebase` flag.

Comment: Do you know roughly how to do the equivalent in EGit/Eclipse.

Comment: We work with this plugin rather than use the command line. I'm assuming EGit sends the equivalent commands to the server. Documentation very good for command line users not so good for Egit users

Comment: This might be a better:  http://m-sohn.blogspot.com/2013/11/interactive-rebase-with-egit-32.html

Comment: Would I be right in assuming that its necessary to have the commits done in a branch as the interactive merge seems to assume you are taking the commits from a branch

Comment: This is a good answer, but it still leaves the question, why *aren't* you using branches?  That's a fundamental part of version control.

Comment: I agree with @nilpo 100% (thus my +1), *unless* the dev tasks are not large.

Comment: to answer on branches we work on different features that are quite quick to do and don't step on each others toes. There is only the 2 of us.                 I think I have got much better at Git since doing this and what I was doing wrong was not merging and marking as merged the files from my colleague in the synchronies view of egit. Since doing  This it has lead to much better results and I no longer get the fast forward errors. So i have not had to rebase my work.